# Jquery auto reload freezes website for a few seconds

Tags: jquery, load, reload

I use the code below to auto reload a small frame at the top of my website every 60 seconds, but every time it reloads, it freezes (cannot click on anything) for about 10-20 seconds, sometimes even constantly until the page is manually refreshed. Is there a way to stop this happening?

```
 $(function() {
$('#stats').load('statsto.php');

    var visibleInterval = 60000;
    var invisibleInterval = 60000;

    $(function() {
        setTimer();
        $(document).bind('visibilitychange'), function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            setTimer();    
        };
    });

    function displayStats() {
        $('#stats').load('statsto.php');
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    }

    function setTimer() {
        timer = setInterval(displayStats, (document.hidden) ? invisibleInterval : visibleInterval);
    }

});
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in there. Is this the real code?

Comment: what do you mean by freeze? mouse stops moving? can't click on anything?

Comment: By freeze I mean I cannot click on anything

Comment: Have you for some reason turned off asynch (do you have `$.ajaxSetup({ async: false });` or something like that anywheree?)

Answer (score 1):

More than likely your ajax request has `async: false`.  Try changing that to true to allow the ajax to be performed while other stuff is done.

Comment: async is set to `async: true`

Comment: @Andy is it possible to get access to the page or an example that shows whats going on.  Kind of hard to debug